# How to jump directly to the last line of the current table cell in Word 2007?

Tags: vba, navigation, ms-word, office-2007

I have a large Table in MS Word 2007 (spanning several pages) and each row contains a lot of text.

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Word 2007 to directly jump to the last line of the current table cell to add text at the "bottom" of the cell?

If there is not, how could I do that with VBA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to go to the last row in the current table (in the same column).

The equivalent in VBA:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdColumn
```

**EDIT**

(Updated after new information in the question)

Sorry, I misunderstood. OK, then, try the following to find the end of the cell in VBA:

```
Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdCell
```

I don't know if it can be done with keyboard shortcuts, maybe someone else knows?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe I formulated my question badly: I want to jump to the **last text line in the current cell** (not to the last row in the table). (I edited my question to hopefully make clearer what I need)

Comment: thanks a lot - that works. One more question: If the end of the current cell is out of the currently visible area of the page, word does not **scroll to the new cursor position**, when I use `Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdCell` . Can you tell me how to automatically scroll down to the new cursor position?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do it, but you could just add `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range` after `Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdCell` to make sure the insertion point is visible.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of keys are possible but I'm not sure it will work in every case:

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> (to jump to the next cell), <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>,
- Or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (current cell selected), <kbd>Right</kbd> (end of selection = end of current cell)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the best way in VBA be to just refer to the last row?

```
table.Cell(table.rows.count, yourColumnNumberToUpdate).Range.Text = table.Cell(table.rows.count, yourColumnNumberToUpdate).Range.Text + "What ever you want to add to the bottom of the cell"
```

Of course if there was text already in the cell you would want to add a carriage return so the added text was at the bottom of the cell.